# Merging Rails databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, merge

I have two databases with the same structure. The tables have an integer as a primary key as used in Rails.

If I have a patients table, I will have one patient using primary key 123 in one database and another patient using the same primary key in the other database.

What would you suggest for merging the data from both databases?

Comment: What database engine are you using? Also (I don't have much Rails experience), does Rails assign the ids for new records or does the database engine do it?

Comment: In Rails the ids are assigned by the database using a sequence or autoincrement integer field type.

Answer (score 10):

Set both your databases up with entries in config/database.yml, then generate a new migration.

Use ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection to switch between the two databases in the migration like this:

```
def self.up
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development
  patients = Patient.find(:all)
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :production
  patients.each { |patient| Patient.create patient.attributes.except("id") }
end
```

YMMV depending on the number of records and the associations between models.

Comment: I am facing problem when i switched database from development to production, then the records on patients variable updated. e.g i have 10 users in development and 3 in production when i switched database the patients variable converted from 10 users to 3. Can you please help. :)

Answer (score 5):

If your databases are exactly the same (the data doesn't require custom processing) and there aren't too many records, you could do this (which allows for foreign keys):

**Untested...** But you get the idea

```
#All models and their foreign keys
tales = {Patients => [:doctor_id, :hospital_id],
         Doctors => [:hospital_id],
         Hospitals}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development

max_id = tables.map do |model|  
  model.maximum(:id)
end.max + 1000


tables.each do |model, fks|  
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development
  records = model.find(:all)

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :production
  records.each do |record|
    #update the foreign keys
    fks.each do |attr|
      record[attr] += max_id if not record[attr].nil?
    end
    record.id += max_id

    model.create record.attributes
  end
end
```

If you have a LOT of records you might have to portion this out somehow... do it in groups of 10k or something.

Answer (score 0):

BTW it probably makes more sense for this to be a rake or capistrano task rather than a migration.