# Merging development data into production data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, production

We've deployed an application last week. The problem is that we have some development data that we'd like to migrate to production, but the production database is already in use. So just importing and exporting SQL will pose the problem that the IDs won't match anymore.

Now, I've thought about eager loading all data into base objects, but there's no such thing as one base object. There are four objects with only has_many associations and a lot of objects with multiple belongs_to associations.

Is there any other method of exporting and importing that we could use to achieve what we want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to dump the dev data to yaml ([this plugin does that](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) and there are probably others that will do the trick), and then use db/seeds.rb to write a script loading its contents and using rails models to recreate them on the production db with rake db:seed

rake db:seed won't hose your data (it just loads db/seeds.rb, see the source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L286) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L452)), but be sure to backup your data before anything :)

I'd suggest playing with a sandbox app and db clone before going ahead and running this on production.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would think DB Seed would not work with existing data. I'd be nervous you'd lose existing data.

Comment: rake db:seed itself won't hose any existing data, it just loads db/seeds.rb, which is just a place to have a script with access to your app's environment. nothing keeping it from loading an yaml fixture. here's the task's source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L286

Comment: in any case, be sure to backup your data :) and I'd suggest playing with a sandbox app and db clone before going ahead and running this on production. running statements in the console first can help in putting the script together

Comment: I had looked at yaml_db, but exporting the DB to YAML didn't keep any of the relations when importing, so we threw it out. Writing a seed script (we wrote a rake task, but the idea is the same) got way too complex. We had to keep arrays with old IDs and new IDs, compare them and change them accordingly. It just didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, maybe seeing your models, or a sample of them, and the script would help us understand better what you're facing. Just found another thread on this, btw, with some interesting suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169240/merging-rails-databases

Comment: Just so you have an idea, we have an Entry model that has references to a User, Company, Category, Project and Task, where tasks have HABTM relations to projects, a company has many clients and projects, projects belong to a client, users HABTM companies and entries et cetera. It got a bit too complex, so we decided we would rebuild the data using the application itself, which took a couple of hours. It's a one time thing and a lesson for the future. I've accepted your question because I do think a seed script (or rake task with two databases) will be able to do the trick if done properly.

Comment: thanks, and I'm glad you got it working in the end. data migrations can definitely be painful :)

Answer (score 0):

Export the development data as CSV, yaml, XML, or whatever format you want to use for this. Then you have a choice of what to do:

If only importing the data once then you can use a migration to load the data from the specified files. Be sure to include the files with the migration when you check it in to source control.

Load the data using the console (script/console production) and entering the commands manually. This might be a nicer way since you can examine the data that's going in and adjust as necessary.

If you're going to be doing this more then once then write a rake task that when given a filename or other identifier load the data into the database.

Comment: I think our data is a bit too complex for this solution. For instance, we have a model with 250 records which has 8 belongs_to associations. Recreating the data in the application itself would be easier than doing it manually in the console. You did give me an idea though, I'll elaborate on this later.